# Is there a shorter way to extract a date from a string?

Tags: r

I wrote code to extract the date from a given string. Given

```
  > "Date: 2012-07-29, 12:59AM PDT"
```

it extracts

```
  > "2012-07-29"
```

The problem is my code looks lengthy and cumbersome to read. I was wondering if was a more elegant way of doing this.

```
  raw_date = "Date: 2012-07-29, 12:59AM PDT"

  #extract the string from raw date
  index = regexpr("[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}", raw_date) #returns 'start' and 'end' to be used in substring

  start = index #start represents the character position 's'. start+1 represents '='
  end = attr(index, "match.length")+start-1
  date = substr(raw_date,start,end); date
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `strptime()` to parse time objects:

```
R> strptime("Date: 2012-07-29, 11:59AM PDT", "Date: %Y-%m-%d, %I:%M%p", tz="PDT")
[1] "2012-07-29 11:59:00 PDT"
R>
```

Note that I shifted your input string as I am unsure that 12:59AM exists...  Just to prove the point, shifted by three hours (expressed in seconds, the base units):

```
R> strptime("Date: 2012-07-29, 11:59AM PDT", 
+>          "Date: %Y-%m-%d, %I:%M%p", tz="PDT") + 60*60*3
[1] "2012-07-29 14:59:00 PDT"
R>
```

Oh, and if you just want the date, it is of course even simpler:

```
R> as.Date(strptime("Date: 2012-07-29, 11:59AM PDT", "Date: %Y-%m-%d"))
[1] "2012-07-29"
R>
```

Comment: +1 for the pointer to `strptime` and its siblings. Quite powerful, I should use it more often.

Comment: While we're at `strptime` and close friends like `format`: is there a "tag" for easily formatting "to quarters"? Similar to the `%U` tag that handles calendar weeks? I'd like `"2012-08-01"` to be turned into, e.g `"2012-Q3"`, without having to query a `POSIXlt`'s `$mon` attribute to determine what quarter we're in.

Comment: Not that I know of. The formats come from the C library and are quite standard.  So you may have to extract the month component from POSIXlt as you said.

Answer (score 6):

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
x <- "Date: 2012-07-29, 12:59AM PDT"
as.Date(substr(x, 7, 16), format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 4):

As (pretty much) always, you've got multiple options here. Though none of them really frees you from getting used to some basic regular expression syntax (or its close friends).

```
raw_date <- "Date: 2012-07-29, 12:59AM PDT"
```

### Alternative 1

```
> gsub(",", "", unlist(strsplit(raw_date, split=" "))[2])
[1] "2012-07-29"
```

### Alternative 2

```
> temp <- gsub(".*: (?=\\d?)", "", raw_date, perl=TRUE)
> out <- gsub("(?<=\\d),.*", "", temp, perl=TRUE)
> out
[1] "2012-07-29"
```

### Alternative 3

```
> require("stringr")
> str_extract(raw_date, "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")
[1] "2012-07-29"
```

Comment: Don't use regexps to deal with dates. Regexps do *not* know what a valid date is -- you *will* hit something like a Feb 30 that way.

Comment: That's true. Just took this in a "hit and run" manner but if it's really a fully standardized format that you can trust I guess it doesn't make a difference at the end of the day. But I sure should have known better considering the many times pure regex-based code caused a lot of trouble ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Regex with backreferencing works:

```
> sub("^.+([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]).+$","\\1","Date: 2012-07-29, 12:59AM PDT")
[1] "2012-07-29"
```

But @Dirk is right that parsing it as a date is the right way to go.

Comment: Don't do that. Work with date / time object instead. This isn't Perl :)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel But if `perl=TRUE` then this *is* Perl right? :-)

Comment: Touche, can't counter than logic :)